Cannot install ChromaDB on python:3.12.3-alpine3.19 Docker image
I am trying to install python dependencies on a python:3.12.3-alpine3.19 Docker immage. When the requirements.txt file is processed I get the following error:
7.932 ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.5.12 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.12; 0.5.13 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.12; 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
7.932 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.18.0 (from versions: none)
7.933 ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime==1.18.0
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt && pip uninstall

Even if I try to install an older version of python I still get an error:
From Python:3.10.14-alpine3.19.
61.58 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.18.0 (from versions: none)
61.58 ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime==1.18.0

Why is this happening?

It seems that Chroma vector DB does not work (or not out of the box) with Alpine distributions of Python. I switched to Bookworm and was able to install Chroma and use it in the script running in my Docker container.

It's likely because onnxruntime is built using glibc. Alpine uses musl C standard library, whereas debian bookworm and many other linux distros use glibc.
